# Benchmarking Monte Carlo simulations of polymers

Tags: software, high-performance-computing, monte-carlo, polymers, benchmark-timings

I have written a simulation engine in C++ to run a Monte Carlo simulation of polymers on a lattice. My code basically plants a polymer on a lattice, and performs certain Monte Carlo moves, including but not limited to the following:
[image]

I ensure that excluded volume effects are maintained in this system as it evolves (if two monomers overlap, energy diverges, and move is rejected). Now that my software is running, I would like to run some benchmarks on it.

My first thought is calculating Flory exponents. If I run my simulation with excluded volume and a certain monomer-solvent interaction, I should get a Flory exponent $\nu$ such that
$$\langle R_g ^2 \rangle \propto N^\nu $$

If I have excluded volume interactions on a 3D lattice with no monomer-solvent interaction $\epsilon _{ms} = 0$, I should expect to see a $\nu$ of 0.6. My question is, is there a scaling behavior to be seen when I have a $\epsilon_{ms} >0$ (bad solvent) and a $\epsilon _{ms} < 0$ (good solvent)?

Are there any other benchmarks I should run to check my simulation engine is functioning up to the mark?

I would appreciate any advice you have for me.

Comment: Check the software Cassandra by Maginn at Notre Dame. They probably have benchmarks for their monte carlo moves. https://cassandra.nd.edu/. I think Daan Frenkel also has done alot of this, so maybe see if he has a website/code around with benchmarks. Same with Vlugt

Comment: Was the suggestion by Wesley helpful?

Comment: Yes, @NikeDattani!

Comment: Wow! Good news! Enough to write a self-answer?

Comment: @Wesley Your speculations turned out to be helpful! Since some time has passed now, do you think you could expand that into an answer?

Comment: @NikeDattani sure, I can do that

Answer (score 6):

Alot of the early pioneering in Monte Carlo (MC) moves were done initially using lattices. While I am not directly aware of places to look for benchmarks, the pioneers in the 90's for Monte Carlo moves I would say are Daan Frenkel, Thijs Vlugt, Berend Smidt, Edward Maginn and others.

Professor Edward Maginn hosts the Monte Carlo code [Cassandra](https://cassandra.nd.edu/) from Notre Dame. Daan Frenkel and Berend Smidt wrote the textbook(Bible) [Understanding Molecular Simulation: From algorithms to applications](https://www.elsevier.com/books/understanding-molecular-simulation/frenkel/978-0-12-267351-1), and they have accompanying code written in Fortran, with excerpts written by Vlugt.

This would be where I would start: I would check out Prof. Maginn's software Cassandra for benchmarks, and try to find the Fortran code for Frenkel & Smit, or even just check Frenkel & Smit's textbook which is riddled with pseudocode.

You can also check out [MCCCS Towhee](http://towhee.sourceforge.net/), another well known MC simulation package, but it is notoriously difficult with its documentation.

Comment: Panagiotopoulous is another one, and has fortran code available. Not sure if applicable to lattice though, tends to favor VLE